# How to create a dataset using columns from another table in R?

Tags: r

This maybe complicated and hard to explain. Let's say I have a dataframe that have 4 columns date, id, response_1, and response_2: id column has unique values, response_1 variable contains values of 1 and 0, and response_2 variable uses response_1 values to determine whether to assign 1 and 0 to the unique id. If the id has a value of 0 in the response_1 variable it assign the value of 0 to response_2 variable, but once the id has a value of 1 in the response_1 variable it stays 1 in the response_2 variable regardless of value in response_1 (please see id 1 and 3).

```
sample <- data.frame(date = c("2020-04-17", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-17",
                              "2020-05-13", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-13",
                              "2020-06-12", "2020-06-12", "2020-06-12",
                              "2020-06-19", "2020-06-19"),
                     id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,4,5,1),
                     response_1=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1),
                     response_2=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))

         date id response_1 response_2
1  2020-04-17  1          0          0
2  2020-04-17  2          1          1
3  2020-04-17  3          0          0
4  2020-05-13  1          1          1
5  2020-05-13  2          0          1
6  2020-05-13  3          1          1
7  2020-06-12  1          0          1
8  2020-06-12  3          0          1
9  2020-06-12  4          0          0
10 2020-06-19  5          1          1
11 2020-06-19  1          1          1
```

What I want to calculate using this dataset is seeing in each day how many unique id we had and how many turned into 1 since the beginning of dataset. For instance on June 12, we had total of 4 unique id (1,2,3, and 4) in the whole dataset and 3 of them turned into 1 (id 1,2,and 3) 4 was still 0.

Like this:

```
result <- data.frame(date=c("04-17-2020", "05-13-2020","06-12-2020", "06-19-2020"),
                     count_id = c(3,3,4,5), total=c(1,3,3,4))

        date count_id total
1 04-17-2020        3     1
2 05-13-2020        3     3
3 06-12-2020        4     3
4 06-19-2020        5     4
```

What will be the best way to accomplish this in R?

Comment: In your example for June 12 only three unique IDs exist. Please, edit your question. By the way, do you require to see if in variables `response_1` and `response_2` there were changes (from 0 to 1?)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `duplicated` with `cumsum` to get count of cumulative unique id's and take `cumsum` of `response_1` variable. For each `date` we then select the last row to get final count.

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(response_11 = response_1 * as.integer(!duplicated(response_1))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(count_id = cumsum(!duplicated(id)),
         total = cumsum(response_11)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  select(date, count_id, total)

#  date       count_id total
#  <chr>         <int> <dbl>
#1 2020-04-17        3     1
#2 2020-05-13        3     3
#3 2020-06-12        4     3
#4 2020-06-19        5     4
```

Comment: I did not explain it clearly. I am not looking to count how many distinct id I had on that day but rather how many we had since the start of dataset. So since 4/17 we had total of 4 unique id on 6/12 (1,2,3,4) and 3 of them (1,2, 3) turn into 1 in response_1. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I misunderstood the question earlier. I have edited the answer to reflect those changes. Would `response_1` variable be 1 for a particular `id` only once?

Comment: No, it can be 1 or 0 any number of times in response_1 (id 1 could have been 1 again on 6/12) , but once it is 1 in response_1 it always stays 1 in response_2. For  instance id 1 in variable response_1 turns 1 on 5/13, and  starting 5/13 it always stays 1 in response_2.

Comment: Which part you didn't understand? `!duplicated(id)` gives `TRUE` `id` value which occur the first time. Using `cumsum` we get number of unique id's till that point of time.

Comment: Thank you! since 1 can occur multiple times for an id the codes are not working correctly. I added another record to my dataset with id 1 and it had a value of 1 in variable response_1 and I got value of 5 in variable total instead of 4

Comment: Can you update your question with that example so that we'll have a reproducible example to test our solution.

Comment: I updated my question. Thank you so much for all your help!